# Unable to Open Appcelerator Studio after fresh Install

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am stuck with an issue. I have installed the Appcelerator studio on my Macbook from Appcelerator dashboard and it was installed successfully. But when I try to open it, below message appears.

[image]

I also tried to install using the command-line but no success.

After opening the log file mentioned in the message I found below log

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-06 23:19:28.145
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: com.aptana.commandline.launcher.LauncherApplication, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what java version do you run?

Comment: my java version is 1.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is something to do with the JDK version.  can you move to JDK 1.8.131?  Here is the direct link 
http://go.appcelerator.com/installer_jdk_mac

Let me know how it goes.

Thanks

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have installed JDK 1.8.131. But still unable to open the Studio. The same issue exists. Also as per the document http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Studio_5.0.0.GA_Release_Note , I am unable to find .ini file at specified location.

Comment: GO > Mac OS X: ~/Documents/<Studio Workspace>/.metadata/.log and check java version. If you have multiple java please remove all and keep only JDK 1.8.131. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok Yes, Actually multiple JDK's were causing the issue even after installing JDK 1.8.13. It's working now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after a long time struggling with this I solve the problem removing the current jdk that I had and installed JDK 1.8.131 specifically.

To remove that in my mac I had to follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903) steps